# How to make the Jade template compress inline javascript automatically?

Tags: node.js, pug

when I check the html page source, the HTML tags and text content are compressed without blank and line, but inline javascript.

Comment: I had this problem too, and didn't think it was important enough to compress it manually. Uglifying the javascript would be more useful IMHO. But I would like to add that semicolons are not required in javascript, and compressing inline javascript automatically would need to first parse and understand which places need semicolons.

Answer (score 5):

Just discovered something that works for me in Jade v0.30.0:

1. Rename your .js file with a .uglify extension
2. In your Jade template, use:

   ```
   include name-of-javascript-file.uglify
   ```

*Why it works:* Digging into the Jade source code, I discovered a file called `filters.js`.  In there, you'll see a dependency on `transformers`. In `lib/transformers.js` (of the transformers module), you will see the various transform utilities, including `uglify`.  Apparently, Jade will call on any of those transformers if you match the right file extension in your `include` declaration.

Comment: Very strange, how does this work? Any chance there's a blog post I can go read?

Comment: Fascinating! And this is intentional behaviour and won't be patched up at any point?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about it and haven't tested it yet, but you can probalby add a filter and utilize [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/). For example

```
var uglyParser = require("uglify-js").parser;
var uglyUgly   = require("uglify-js").uglify;

var uglify = function(str) {
  var ast = uglyParser.parse(str);
  ast = uglyUgly.ast_mangle(ast);
  ast = uglyUgly.ast_squeeze(ast);
  return uglyUgly.gen_code(ast);
}
```

To be honest, I'm not sure where to put that in jade so it's treated as a filter. For now you should be able to just stick it at https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/lib/filters.js.

The usage in jade would then be:

```
script(type="text/javascript")
  :uglify
    <Your JavaScript Code>
```

Again I haven't tested it. But I think it should work. I'll test it later today.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/filters/), you can use any JSTransformer as a jade filter. So, where you would normally do this to inline JS:

```
script.
  (function doSomething () { … })();
```

you should do it like this:

```
script
  :uglify-js
    (function doSomething () { … })();
```

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks! (Note that the 2nd example doesn't have a dot after `script`). One drawback though is that when doing this, one loses syntax highlighting in vscode.